# How do I map <CR>/<Enter> properly in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I found vimrc key remapping of / in [vim-better-default plugin](https://github.com/liuchengxu/vim-better-default/blob/master/plugin/default.vim#L233) and added to my config.

The remapping works as expected, but this remap also causes an issue with jump using the relative number. For example, when I run `5<CR>`, I need to type enter once more for it to work and it only jumps for 4 lines. The output in the bottom display is `:.,.+4`

I tried adding these but it did not work either.

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <CR> <CR>
autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <CR> <CR>
```

Thanks,

Comment: So you're used to use "enter" for one thing; then you remapped it to do another thing, and the old thing doesn't work anymore. So what do you want then?

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a way to handle this like disabling the mapping only when enter is typed after number is entered or something. But I found I can just use jk to move around instead of enter, so it is good now.

Comment: It's possible to map a key to do totally different things depending on counter "presence-absence", but that's rather confusing and should not be recommended to anyone. Whether to use "jay-kay", or "plus-minus", or "up-down" is your choice.